# How to pass a dictionary data in tensorflow function

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am new to tensorflow. 
I want to build a 3 layer neural network,

**i)** I have declared weight `W` inside `tf.function` for which it is throwing the following error:

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

**ii)** And also I have created a dictionary data of sample_batch which has `x` :features and `y`:labels which I want to pass to `tf.function` and use it later.But I am not understanding how to do it?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 @tf.function 

 def forward_pass1(batch):

    print((batch))

    W = tf.Variable(tf.initializers.TruncatedNormal(stddev=np.sqrt(2.0 / 784))(shape=(784,      128)), name="W")

    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(128)), name="b")

    hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(batch['x'], W) + biases)

    print(hidden1)

sample_batch = federated_train_data[5][-1]

forward_pass1((sample_batch))
```

Can any one please help?

Comment: try initializing  variables `W` and `biases` outside the function

Comment: kindly accept my answer, and also checkout writing a custom layers in tf

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

Initialize the variables outside the function and pass it as arguments

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.initializers.TruncatedNormal(stddev=np.sqrt(2.0 / 784))(shape=(784,      128)), name="W")

biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(128)), name="b")
```

Your function should be like this:

```
@tf.function 

 def forward_pass1(batch,W,biases):

    print((batch))


    hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(batch['x'], W) + biases)

    print(hidden1)

sample_batch = federated_train_data[5][-1]

forward_pass1((sample_batch))
```

The better way is to do in this way as per the [Tensorflow Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models):

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers


class Linear(layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, units=128, input_dim=784):
    super(Linear, self).__init__()
    w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    self.W = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units),
                                              dtype='float32'),
                         trainable=True)
    b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.biases = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,),
                                              dtype='float32'),
                         trainable=True)

  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.W) + self.biases)

x = tf.ones((2, 2))
linear_layer = Linear(4, 2)
y = linear_layer(x)
print(y)
```